# Php debugging with Aptana Studio and Xdebug or Zend debugger on OS X

Tags: php, debugging, macos, aptana, xdebug

Have you managed to get Aptana Studio debugging to work? I tried following this, but I don't see `Windows -> Preferences -> Aptana -> Editors -> PHP -> PHP Interpreters` in my menu (I have `PHP plugin` installed) and any attempt to set up the servers menu gives me "socket error" when I try to debug. `Xdebug` is installed, confirmed through `php info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using ZendDebugger with Eclipse (on OS X) for a while now and it works great!

Here's the recipe that's worked well for me.

1. install Eclipse PDT via "All in one" package at: http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt
2. install ZendDebugger.so (http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt)
3. configure your php.ini w/ the ZendDebugger extenssion (info below)

Configuring ZendDebugger:

1. edit php.ini
2. add the following:

   [Zend]
   zend_extension=/full/path/to/ZendDebugger.so
   zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
   zend_debugger.connector_port=10013

Now run "php -m" in the command line to output all the installed modules. If you see the following then its installed just fine

```
[Zend Modules]  
Zend Debugger
```

Now restart Apache so that it reloads PHP w/ the ZendDebugger. Create a dummy page with  in it and examine the output to make sure the PHP apache module picked up ZendDebugger as well. If it's setup right you will see something like the following text somewhere in phpinfo()'s output.

> with Zend Debugger v5.2.14, Copyright (c) 1999-2008, by Zend Technologies

OK - but you wanted Aptana Studio... at this point I install the Aptana Studio Plugin into the PDT build of Eclipse. The instructions for that are at: http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration

That setup has served me well for a while - hopefully it helps you too

-Arin

Comment: > 1. ...
> 2. install ZendDebugger.so (http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt)

How is installed ZendDebugger.so? i can't find it in the link... :P

Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Aptana Studio, but if you are looking for a PHP XDebug debugger client on OS X, you can try [MacGDBp](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/) (Free/GPL).

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a old thread but I was having the same problem with Aptana Studio 3 and FireFox. If anyone is having this problem make sure that FireFox has FireBug **V1.8.X** installed, any other version might give you the same problem...

Hope this helps